# Why does my remote automatically trigger the self-timer on EOS60D?

Tags: timelapse, canon-60d, camera-controls, self-timer

I have purchased a Chinese remote control.  While setting it to interval shooting for time-lapse, it automatically runs the self-timer for 2 seconds, which is unnecessary and eats up the battery. How do I make the timer stop?

Comment: What model remote are you using?

Comment: A 2-sec delay is often useful for that sort of thing, as it allows any camera shake to dissipate.

Answer (score 1):

The self time or 2sec delay would be a configurable option on your camera. Follow this YouTube tutorial for details on how to enable/disable this option:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VOpuaqHqSM

Alternatively this could be an option on your intervalometer, in which case I would recommend you consult your manual. Usually though an intervalometer is a form of advanced remote. I.E. You set the time and then the intervalometer completes the circuit everytime the time finishes.